# Resend messages after timeout

Tags: java, rabbitmq, jms, spring-amqp

I have a list of objects that I put in Spring AMQP. Objects come from the controller. There is a service that processes these objects. And this service may crash with an OutOfMemoryException. Therefore, I run several instances of the application.

There is a problem: when the service crashes, I lose the received messages. I read about NACK. And could use it in case of Exception or RuntimeException. But my service crashes in Error. Therefore, I cannot send NACK. Is it possible to set a timeout in AMQP, after which I would be sent a message again if I had not confirmed the messages that had arrived earlier?

Here is the code I wrote:

```
public class Exchanges {
    public static final String EXC_RENDER_NAME = "render.exchange.topic";
    public static final TopicExchange EXC_RENDER = new TopicExchange(EXC_RENDER_NAME, true, false);
}

public class Queues {
    public static final String RENDER_NAME = "render.queue.topic";
    public static final Queue RENDER = new Queue(RENDER_NAME);
}

@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
public class RenderRabbitEventListener extends RabbitEventListener {
    private final ApplicationEventPublisher eventPublisher;

    @RabbitListener(bindings = @QueueBinding(value = @Queue(Queues.RENDER_NAME),
                                             exchange = @Exchange(value = Exchanges.EXC_RENDER_NAME, type = "topic"),
                                             key = "render.#")
    )
    public void onMessage(Message message, Channel channel) {
        String routingKey = parseRoutingKey(message);
        log.debug(String.format("Event %s", routingKey));
        RenderQueueObject queueObject = parseRender(message, RenderQueueObject.class);
        handleMessage(queueObject);
    }
    public void handleMessage(RenderQueueObject render) {
        GenericSpringEvent<RenderQueueObject> springEvent = new GenericSpringEvent<>(render);
        springEvent.setRender(true);
        eventPublisher.publishEvent(springEvent);
    }
}
```

And this is the method that sends messages:

```
    @Async ("threadPoolTaskExecutor")
    @EventListener (condition = "# event.queue")
    public void start (GenericSpringEvent <RenderQueueObject> event) {
        RenderQueueObject renderQueueObject = event.getWhat ();
        send (RENDER_NAME, renderQueueObject);
}
private void send(String routingKey, Object queue) {
    try {
        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(routingKey, objectMapper.writeValueAsString(queue));
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        log.warn("Can't send event!", e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close the connection to get the message re-queued.

It's best to terminate the application after an OOME (which, of course, will close the connection).

Comment: Gary, yes, it works.  As soon as the connection is closed, the message is replicated to a free instance. But if I run asynchronously, then it stops working.

Comment: But, as I said, an OOME should be considered fatal and you should stop the app - you need to figure out why you are getting OOMEs.